# I am looking for an adjective, similar to "holding a grudge"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective that describes a person who is not willing to forgive or excuse someone's faults or wrong-doings from the past (other than "unforgiving"). For the ones who speak German, that word would be "nachtragend".

Answer (score 24):

[Resentful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Resentful):

> - Full of, characterized by, or inclined to feel indignant ill will.

Comment: This doesn't carry the meaning of "past wrongdoing".  Success can engender resentment with no wrongdoing whatsoever.

Comment: Resentment :Indignation or ill will stemming from a feeling of having been wronged or offended. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Resentment

Comment: ... and that goes on to mention causes such as envy "begrudging admiration" that have nothing to do with wrongdoing.  In that case, there is "a feeling of having been wronged *by the world/society/fate/fortune*", which does not require the target of resentment to have done wrong.

Comment: Resentment: 
a feeling of displeasure or indignation at someone or something regarded as the cause of injury or insult; pique; irritation.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Resentment

Answer (score 18):

In contrast with the more technical options presented in most other answers, and yet also hinted at in a few of those same answers: consider *bitter*, the emotional state of someone experiencing the hardships you describe. I think it fits the bill pretty closely and is also well-suited for casual, contemporary conversation. It's succinct, relatable regardless of your vocabulary, and even a little poetic I'd say.

Answer (score 16):

When the feeling includes wanting to do something about it, *[vindictive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/vindictive)*

> Having or showing a strong or unreasoning desire for revenge:
>   *the criticism was both vindictive and personalized*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: The significance of revenge in this word's meaning would make it out-of-place if Gunter's intent doesn't include revenge.

Comment: @talrnu I agree in part. A yearning for revenge (even if there were no real intent to act) would be encompassed, but a mere resentment and anger would not.

Answer (score 6):

**implacable**:

> 1. incapable of being placated or pacified; unappeasable
> 2. inflexible; intractable - [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/implacable)

Additional synonyms:

> ruthless, cruel, relentless, uncompromising...unrelenting, merciless, unforgiving, inexorable, unyielding, remorseless, pitiless, unbending... - [Collins Thesaurus](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/implacable?showCookiePolicy=true)

Answer (score 6):

My family would say the person is still "stewing" about it. I don't know if this is just an American idiom but I suspect not since there are so many other countries who make stew.  The term means "a slow boil" literally. So it can refer to anger, agitation, or worry.  But, I have used it for "holding a grudge".  Have you considered "negatively invested"?

Comment: We use stewing too.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to bib's excellent suggestion *vindictive*, you might consider *rancorous*, which Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) defines thus:

> **rancorous** *adj.* (ca. 1570) marked by rancor [defined by MW as "bitter, deep-seated ill will"] : deeply malevolent {*rancorous* envy}

S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word* (1968) distinguishes between *vindictive* and *rancorous* as follows:

> **Vindictive** means spitefully vengeful, and suggests the harboring of grudges for imagined wrongs until the *vindictive* person, with satisfaction and perhaps even enjoyment, sees the object of his hatred suffer. ... *Rancorous* suggests a festering ill will, perhaps stemming from resentment, over some real or fancied wrong. It does not, however, like *vindictive* and *spiteful*, necessarily imply a desire to hurt—only a deep-seated malice.

It's interesting that, in Hayakawa's telling, *vindictive*, *rancorous*, and *unforgiving* span a wide range of possibilities as to the legitimacy of the grudge, from "imagined wrong" in the case of *vindictive* to "real or fancied wrong" in the case of *rancorous* to actual injury in the case of *unforgiving* (since forgiveness doesn't make sense in situations where there is no wrong to forgive).

Comment: One of my favorite words! I like to imagine Jabba's rancor is a bit rancorous...

Comment: Lovely! I was thinking of *begrudging* and the like, but *rancorous* is a much better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Resentful and vindictive are great. Many people commonly use ***bitter*** too.

[bitter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bitter)
5. characterized by intense antagonism or hostility:
     *bitter hatred*.
6. hard to admit or accept:
     *a bitter lesson.*
7. resentful or cynical:
     *bitter words.*

E.g.: "A poorly treated child is commonly a bitter adult to his parents."

or

"A poorly treated child commonly treats his parents bitterly once an adult."

Answer (score 2):

You have two good options in your question, IMHO - Unforgiving, which you don't want to use, and Grudge Holder, which isn't an idiom in any dictionary I can find, but communicates what you want to say.

As for other suggestions available at the time of writing, Vindictive and Vengeful go the extra action or intention into vengeance, Resentful could be short term, or specific, and Implacable doesn't really communicate the same thing, it's more an innate inability, less an intentional entrenching into bitterness.

Comment: Grudges are *nursed*, idiomatically.

Comment: @twip Grudges are also held, idiomatically. Different connotations.

Comment: @twip *Grudge nurser* conjures imagery which I imagine is poorly aligned with Gunter's intent. I, for one, love it.

Answer (score 2):

The closest answer is surely [grudge-bearing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grudge-bearing).

Answer (score 1):

> [**vengeful**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vengeful)
>    1. *Desiring vengeance; vindictive*
>    2. *Characterized by or stemming from a desire for revenge*

Answer (score 1):

To begrudge
Or maybe to  resent

Answer (score 1):

1. [revengeful](https://www.google.com/search?q=revengeful&oq=revengeful&aqs=chrome..69i57.7966917j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8): full of or prone to revenge; determined to get even; eager for revenge.
2. [spiteful](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spiteful): full of or motivated by spite; vindictive, full of spite or malice; showing spite; malicious; malevolent; venomous.

Answer (score 0):

pissed off and revengeful/and bent on revenge. A word of elevated style for German nachtragend would be begrudging - too literary in my view.

Comment: Begrudging was actually my first thought, +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Vendetta

noun
1.
a private feud in which the members of the family of a murdered person seek to avenge the murder by killing the slayer or one of the slayer's relatives, especially such vengeance as once practiced in Corsica and parts of Italy.
2.
any prolonged and bitter feud, rivalry, contention, or the like:
a political vendetta.

Answer (score 0):

Sulking may be what you are looking for:

> be silent, morose, and bad-tempered out of annoyance or disappointment.
>
> -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?q=define%20sulking)

In fact, one of the listed synonyms is to *"harbour a grudge"*

Answer (score 0):

What about bemoan

> **Bemoan** transitive verb 1 :to express deep grief or distress over 2 :to
>   regard with displeasure, disapproval, or regret

It's holds a subtle meaning of holding a grudge: making it softer than the other words mentioned. You've got a really nice list of words to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was bitter too, but its derivative *embittered* is probably closer to the OP's original request.

Comment: Please give a rationale for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implacable

> Not placable; not to be appeased; not to be pacified or reconciled; inexorable: as, an implacable prince; implacable malice.

Comment: And the reference...?